# Propagating error for a circle

Tags: error-propagation

The radius of a circle is measured to be $12.1\pm 0.030$ cm

What is the uncertainty in the area of this circle?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Three hints, depending on whether you like playing with numbers, algebra, or calculus:

1. **Numbers**: Calculate the areas of circles with radii 12.1, 12.13, 12.07.
2. **Algebra**: Expand $\pi(r+\varepsilon)^2$ and see how it differs from $\pi r^2$.
3. **Calculus**: Ponder $\delta A \approx \tfrac{dA}{dr} \delta r$